# jQuery selector reference for links

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I've created new links on a site I'm working on for a friend. I reused the jQuery snippet that i'm using for the nav bars but it won't work...my only guess is that i'm not properly using the selector. I've tried $('a.consideralt') and $('ul#conalt li a') (emulating the previously successful syntax) .

The only difference is that the other links are on the index page whereas the new links are in the div where the new page will be loaded. Please see [www.rsgnaturalrearing.com](http://www.rsgnaturalrearing.com) and click the Dog Walking page to see the links in a yellow div. any help is much appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //initial loading of home 
  $('#contentcall').load('home.php');  
  //handle menu items
  $('ul#nav li a').click (function()  {    
    var page = $(this).attr( 'href' );
    $( '#contentcall' ).load( page + '.php' );
    return false;
  });
   $('ul#bottomnavul li a').click (function()  {    
    var page = $(this).attr( 'href' );
    $( '#contentcall' ).load( page + '.php' );
    return false;
  });
     $('a .consideralt').click (function()  {    //new links that will not work
    var page = $(this).attr( 'href' );
    $( '#contentcall' ).load( page + '.php' );
    return false;
  });

  //contact, grooming, buyraw, rawlearning, dogwalking, home INTO CONTENT CAL
  $("body").niceScroll({
    cursorcolor:"#F63E62;;",
  }); 
  //nicescroll jquery custom scrollbar      
});
```

Comment: There's nothing on that page with the class `consideralt`.  Which links are you trying to target?

Comment: @Archer: Look again. ;) There are two links with that class.

Comment: if you click the Dog Walking bone you will see a yellow colored div that has "Raw Food", Training, and Grooming Services links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a 1 pager, you load every single page on click but only bind events on DOM ready. Use the same selector [Guffa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22022781/2324107) is using, but in a delegation mode :

```
 $('#contentcall').on('click', 'a.consideralt', function(){})
```

Comment: Thank you Karl-Andre'! it works! I shall strive to understand!

Answer (score 4):

The selector `a .consideralt` would target an element with `class="consideralt"` *inside* an anchor element.

As the anchor element has the class, you should not have a space in the selector:

```
$('a.consideralt').click (function() {
```

Comment: i've tried that as well.  developer tools show that the browser attempts to GET 'dogwalking' instead of 'dogwalking.php' -- so the query is not adding .php like it should...